# Is there a difference between using $n$ and $\Theta(n)$ in recurrences?

Tags: recurrence-relation, master-theorem

Is there a difference between $T(n)=2T(n/2)+n$ and $T(n)=2T(n/2)+Θ(n)$ when using the master theorem? I've seen it both ways and am a little confused. (Looking for the answer $nlogn$).

Comment: One of the two is a recurrence relation, the other is not. That said, if your read "$\Theta(n)$" correctly here -- i.e. replace it by some $f \in \Theta(n)$ -- you can apply sandwiching to prove that no matter which such $f$ you choose, you always get the same $\Theta$-class for $T$. Therefore, recurrences are routinely simplified in this way. (Remember that for a general result, you have to cover all three cases in your proof.)

Comment: @Raphael I believe that T(n)=2T(n/2)+xxx is recurrent relation with any xxx. Am I incorrect?

Comment: @Bulat I'm fairly certain that we wouldn't call "T(n) = 2T(n/2) + " a recurrence. Nevermind the missing base case.

Comment: @Raphael Why not? T(x) occurs in both parts, is it not enough to fulfil definition of "recurrence"? Wikipedia says "In mathematics, a recurrence relation is an equation that recursively defines a sequence or multidimensional array of values, once one or more initial terms are given: each further term of the sequence or array is defined as a function of the preceding terms". And given that both are missing base case, I don't see the difference.

Comment: @Bulat Wikipedia isn't completely wrong (I'd hesitate to call a recurrence an "equation" in the strict sense; before knowing about implicit definitions, we'd not call it well-defined!) but it gives enough to support my point: "a recurrence relation is an equation". An equation has to fulfill certain criterian, such as all terms are well-defined. Clearly, "" is not (in this context). And, more to the point, adding "$\Theta(n)$" calls into question what "=" means here, i.e. if _equality_ is well-defined.

Answer (score 2):

A recurrence of the form
$$
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + \Theta(n)
$$
is really a shorthand for a recurrence of the form
$$
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + f(n), \text{ where } f(n) = \Theta(n).
$$

Let us consider a recurrence of this form, and let us suppose that $an \leq f(n) \leq bn$, where $a,b > 0$. Consider the more general recurrence
$$
T_c(n) = 2T_c(n/2) + cn,
$$
with the same initial values as the $T(n)$ recurrence. You can prove by induction on $n$ that
$$
T_a(n) \leq T(n) \leq T_b(n).
$$
Therefore, if you can show that $T_c(n) = \Theta(n\log n)$ for all $c$ (where the hidden constant could depend on $c$), then it would follow that also $T(n) = \Theta(n\log n)$.

Comment: Nitpick: the sketch ignores that the sandwich on $f$ only holds for $n \geq N$ for some $N$. Of course, the proof goes through with that restriction (it's just a little more legwork) since we only want asymptotic bounds, anyway.

Comment: I’m using an equivalent definition of asymptotic notation which doesn’t have this additional condition.